# Applying themes styling for dynamically loaded content in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, themes, accordion

I am dynamically adding sections to a JQM accordion collapsible set via Javascript on the page, then attempting to add content to the added section from an HTML file. This part actually works, but the content is inserted without any of the theme styling applied. I have read over numerous posts about this and attempted to use refresh and create to try to get the themes to apply, but without success.

First question is does it matter what appears in the Head of the loaded HTML page? I found that I had to remove the references to jquery and jquerymobile js files, else the headers for the sections are created on top of the existing ones. So all I have is the same styles that were in the page that includes the accordion.

Second, here is how I create the new section for the accordion:

```
$("#NewRequestSection").after('<div id="MyWeatherSection" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="f" data-content-theme="a" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsed="false"><h3 id="WeatherHeader" style="font-size: 28pt;"><img height="70px" width="70px" align="center" style="margin-right: 15px;margin-top: -10px" src="/img/weather.png" />My Weather</h3><div id="WeatherData"></div></div>');

$("#AppsList").collapsibleset('refresh');
```

Again this part works. The new header appears in the accordion just fine.

Now to add content to the new section I use:

```
 $.get('/apps/checkweather/currentweather.htm', function (data) {
        $('#WeatherData').append(data).trigger('create');
    }, 'html');
```

The page's content loads into the section, but without any theme styling. (Note I formally tried using load() with the same results.

I have tried adding refresh to the WeatherData and to its parent MyWeatherSection and even to its parent AppsList without any effect.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I just tested this in a console window in FF 13 using your code (I loaded different data, of course) and it worked with no problem. Is trigger('create') being called? If you call it from the console after the fact, does it style the loaded content?

Comment: Yes, I call trigger('create'). Below is a full sample. I tried with FF and Chrome and in both cases the HTML loads, but does not render using the data-role designations.

Comment: $('<div id="Content"><div data-role="header" data-theme="b"><h4 style="font-size: 30pt; margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;">TITLE</h4><div><div data-role="header" data-theme="e"><div style="font-size: 28pt; font-weight: normal; margin-left: 18px;">Current Conditions</div></div><div><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-theme="c">Dummy button</a></div></div>').appendTo("#Content").trigger("create");

    });

Comment: Sorry Add Comment limits on the number of characters. I can provide a full page sample that illustrations that the data-role (for the headers) are ignored after being added.

Comment: It looks like create should handle the styling. I set up a jsFiddle that pops an alert when create() is called: http://jsfiddle.net/mgcross/8NHL4/ If you add that handler, do you ever get a popup?

Comment: When I run your jsFiddle link, it adds the section and the data, but the data-role="header" and data-theme="b" are not applied.

Comment: Also note there appears to be a bug in JQM in that the section isn't drawn properly. It has rounded corners initially until you collapse and re-expand the section. The corners should only be there when collapsed.

Comment: Maybe it is only headers that aren't styled correctly as your sample seems to handle the styling for the button.

Comment: Oh, I see now, didn't notice the header divs in there. Are you trying to update the page header, or nest a header inside of a collapsible?

Comment: Yes, I want to use headers (or any kind of JQM content) within a section. If I add the class designation to the headers, it seems to work. So maybe the lack of theming only affects headers, though I also found that an element  with the data-role = "page" also breaks things (but maybe that is to be expected).

Comment: Nesting headers or pages within page content probably won't work; you'd probably want to replace the entire page with $.mobile.loadPage.

Comment: try using $.load() instead of $.get(). I ran into the same problem and for some inexplicable reason that fixed it for me